# Do we still use modular subsystems with object-oriented models?

Tags: design, object-oriented, software

I have been reading some old design books (SSADM, JSD.etc) on software engineering that deal mainly with a procedural view of creating systems. I was just wondering if we still use these old techniques e.g. splitting into subsystems and modularization even though programming languages at the moment is mainly object based? Thanks

Comment: Objects are just a specific strategy to split a system into subsystems and modules.

Comment: @mouviciel: objects are a specific strategy to split a system more finegrained than just into subsystems and modules. That does not mean there cannot be modules consisting of only one class or object, but usually not the other way round.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Objects are tools for a far lower level than subsystems and modularization and from a top-down perspective, you would actually think them later in the process of designing the software.

*I am saying this in a top-down view approach, you could eventually do the opposite. In truth, you will likely have some iterative approach wherever you start from. Aniway, classes will not have their places in the high level architecture diagram*

When you talk about designing the system, you're at the high level architecture. You would split the whole systems into components/subsystems.

From that split you would define the role of each components. Then you can start some high level API (interface/network endpoint/...) that defines how you can interact with the component. You may have already some high level interface, incomplete classes/package/module (java or maven or whatever) at that level.

Once it's done you can dig deeper in each components, and that's where you will do stuff like OOP, or DDD, or whatever.

It is possible however that there are some minor differences between how we though subsystems back then and now.

Comment: Case in point: at my work I have a single object that models the entire payments system. An entire team of people, a separated microservice, an isolated payment PCI compliant processor: all tucked behind a single `Payments.makePayment` method call.

Comment: This answer is ok, but let me add a note: *"you would actually think them later in the process of designing the software"* -  "later" assumes a top-down approach in software design, maybe a waterfall approach, which is not the only viable way of doing this. I would suggest a small edit here ...

Comment: Moreover, your answer's last sentence seems to be incomplete - I am not sure what you wanted to express with it?

Comment: @DocBrown thanks for the feedback I made an edit, I wanted to express in my last sentence that if you read a book from 20-30 years ago where modularization and ohers stuff like that was differents, it is possible that there are some differences with how you actually design a system today and now. For instance a cloud one with containers that automatically spawn instances was not something you asw back in the 90's. However I consider that it's the adaptation to a method that stay true today.